# invoke maven pluginManagment objects by reference

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml

I have not found a way to do this, but it seems like a feature that should exist.  Is it possible to invoke a maven-2 plugin by inherited reference?  For example I would like to be able to do something like the following (yes I know you can't do this):

```
<pluginManagment>
<plugin id="exec-inno-setup">
 <artifactId>maven-exec-plugin...
 <executions>...
  <configuration>...</configuration
 <executions>
</plugin>
```

And somewhere in my child POM, I want to do something like:

```
 <pluginRef id="exec-inno-setup">
  <configuration>
   <script>someFile.iss</script>
  </configuration>
 </pluginRef>
```

The question is: is there some way to do this, (or come close).

Comment: And the question is? How to do that anyway?

Comment: Maven is not Ant or Spring. You can't reference anything by id. You can only set defaults in parent poms and inherit them.

Comment: @seanizer Oh but how I wish it was, the XML would be so much less redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *workaround* to your problem is to use maven properties. I'll admit I haven't tried this but I believe it should work...

In your parent you would do something like this...

```
<pluginManagment>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-exec-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <executions>
      ...
      <configuration>
        <script>${maven.exec.plugin.config.script}</script>
      </configuration>
    <executions>
  </plugin>
</pluginManagment>
```

And then in your child project, you just need to define the property...

```
<properties>
    <maven.exec.plugin.config.script>someFile.iss</maven.exec.plugin.config.script>
</properties>
```

This will only work where you childrens' config looks the exact same everywhere except for a few values. If you have different options you need set depending, this won't do it for you and you will have to define the entire plugin and it's configuration in each child pom.xml file.